# What do you call a developer specializing exclusively in microsoft programming languages like T-SQL and C#?

Tags: programming-languages

What would you call this type of specialty? Is "Microsoft Developer" misleading?

Comment: Also, on a note unrelated to my answer - is there any reason your are specializing "exclusively in Microsoft programming languages"? It seems to me that you might be limiting yourself.

Comment: Please note that C# isn't only available on Microsoft. See [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com)

Comment: Blinkered?  Monocultural?

Comment: Borrowed from "In the Heat of the Night" sequel, they call him "Mr. Soft!" though I'd imagine there may be a few other movie references one could combine to form various puns here. ;)

Comment: It depends on whether you're trying to inform, denigrate, obfuscate, or market.

Comment: @Jetti - yes, it is available on other systems through Mono, but it is still a MS language as they head the language development.

Comment: i would call such a person a moron

Answer (score 9):

### I call them a programmer.

...but that's just me.

I don't think you can call someone a Microsoft developer just because they choose the Microsoft stack. Just the same, I wouldn't call anybody an Oracle(company) developer, because they use Java and Oracle(database) (or MySQL).

When suffixing a title with developer, it is usually extremely specific.

Example:

- C# Developer
- Java Developer
- Ruby Developer

and even...

- RoR developer
- .NET developer

Answer (score 4):

As C# is part of the .Net framework, you could call someone who develops using C# a ".Net developer", Microsoft developer is not that misleading, but it's too general

Comment: He specifically mentions T-SQL, which is independent of .NET.

Comment: T-SQL is really knowledge that part and parcel of a developer.  I would say either C# Developer, or if ASP.NET is included, an ASP.NET Developer

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to develop in "Microsoft".  I do know how to develop in C# and T-SQL, as those are languages.  However, calling yourself a Microsoft Developer is pretty generic unless you know how to develop using *all* Microsoft languages / technologies.  Are you also a:

- C++ developer
- BizTalk developer
- MS Access developer
- SharePoint developer
- SSIS developer

There are a lot of different kinds of "developers" in the Microsoft stack.  Be specific.  If you know C# and T-SQL, you're a .NET developer.  T-SQL is pretty much a given for .NET developers, but be sure to list it on your resume.

Answer (score 2):

"Using the Microsoft stack" is usually how I'd describe my specialty where I'm used to using IIS, ASP.Net, Visual Studio, Sitecore and MS-SQL Server as some of the tools in my toolbox for web development stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft developer sounds like someone working for MS (at least to me). So yes, it is misleading, and you definitely can't deduce MS developer -> C# developer, so why would you call them that?

Answer (score 1):

I would call them Microsoft-Fanboy!

Comment: Completely ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

I call them a developer-specializing-exclusively-in-microsoft-programming-languages-like-T-SQL-and-C#.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say Microsoft Developer is misleading, but just calling them a

- Software Developer
- Programmer
- Software Engineer
- C# Developer
- .Net Developer

is better term.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
MSDN - Microsoft Developer Network
It's a network for Microsoft Developers, so I think your expression should be fine.

Comment: I would say the MSDN is Microsoft's Developer Network, rather than the Microsoft Developer Network. Calling yourself a "Microsoft Developer" leaves room for people to misunderstand